# Only one of static files NOT deployed on django app (whitenoise)

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I'm deploying a DJANGO app via heroku, and I'm having trouble with *one* static file. 
*(everything works fine on my local version)*

I've have had no problems so far.

I'm not sure what they are called, but when it comes to static files in DJANGO (using whitenoise)I understand there are two version of each file.
One like:

> 404_style.css

And the other like:

> 404_style.971320e32d34.css

So after I have run **python manage.py collectstatic**

I can only see *404_style.css* on my deployed app, but not *404_style.971320e32d34.css*.
And as my app uses the following reference: *href="/static/404_style.971320e32d34.css"*

 I'm in trouble.

This the relevant settings.py lines:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/js'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/images'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/fonts'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: No, there are not two versions of each file. Django itself does not do anything like what you describe. There are various third-party projects that create a versioned name for static files to help with cachebusting, perhaps you are using one of these?

Comment: Yes, apparently he's using whitenoise, according to the settings. Did you enable the Middleware, as they instruct? http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

Comment: Oh. Well I am a django Noob. Learning something here, thanks! I followed the whitenoise guide you linked and added     `'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',` to INSTALLED_APPS and `whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware` in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.  Now i'm getting these errors: `No module named runserver_nostatic` and `No module named runserver_nostatic`

Comment: @DanielRoseman That's incorrect actually, Django provides this functionality out of the box: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage

Comment: @MadsVJ That error sounds like you have an old version of whitenoise installed. Check that your `requirements.txt` has `whitenoise==3.0` in it

Comment: @MadsVJ Also, your `STATICFILES_DIRS` settings looks strange because once you've included `static` that automatically includes all sub-directories of `static` so you don't need to add `static/js`, `static/fonts` etc. I'm not 100% sure what the effect of doing that will be, but it would definitely be better to avoid it.

Comment: @D.Evans - thanks for the suggestion. Upgrading didn't help though. I changed the *requiments.txt* as you said. Then ran `python manage.py collecstatic` and *pushed to my heroku master*. Nothing changed it seems.

Comment: @MadsVJ Running `collectstatic` locally won't do anything in this case, it needs to be run remotely on Heroku. But Heroku should be doing this automatically when you push. Did you fix your `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting as well?

Comment: @D.Evans Yeah heroku does this when i push the changes (just not perfectly for this file). Yes I did. Unfortunately that didn't change anything.

Comment: @D.Evans This might be related to a warning I get when pushing. I has not caused any troubles yet though. The warning is: `remote:        Found another file with the destination path 'images/dark-bl.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you wan
t, make sure every static file has a unique path.`